# extract date components using subquery in postgres

Tags: postgresql

Shouldn't this just work ?

```
select extract(DAY FROM TIMESTAMP (select to_timestamp('2015-02-23','YY-MM-DD')::timestamp))

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"
LINE 1: select extract(YEAR FROM TIMESTAMP (select to_timestamp('201...
                                        ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "select"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 37
```

As explained here [extract doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT)

Any help is appreciated Thanks :)

Comment: Your error output does not match the query.  Why are you casting a timestamp to timestamp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query will give you the results you wanted:

```
select extract(DAY FROM (select to_timestamp('2015-02-23','YYYY-MM-DD')));
```

Problems I see with your current approach:

- As @harmic pointed out, you don't need the `TIMESTAMP` keyword, because the `to_timestamp()` function already returns a timestamp type.
- In addition, you were casting the result from `to_timestamp()` again to a timestamp, which is not needed
- Your formatting mask for the timestamp is wrong.  You used `YY-MM-DD` but it should really be `YYYY-MM-DD` to take into account that you have a four digit year.  This might not matter in this case, but if you were planning to extract the year, it could matter.

Comment: The subselect is not necessary: `select extract(DAY FROM to_timestamp('2015-02-23','YYYY-MM-DD'))`

Comment: Thanks @ClodoaldoNeto

Answer (score 0):

This does work:

```
psql=> select extract(DAY FROM (select to_timestamp('2015-02-23','YY-MM-DD')::timestamp))
;
 date_part
-----------
        23
(1 row)
```

That is because the syntax of `extract` is:

```
EXTRACT(field FROM source)
```

The keyword `TIMESTAMP` in your example is actually part of a literal timestamp, but you are not using a literal timestamp, rather a scalar subquery expression, so leave `TIMESTAMP` out.

See:

- [syntax for EXTRACT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT)
- [syntax for date/time literals](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html)